# The correlation between two time series and their components

Tags: time-series, probability

Given a timeseries $Y_t$ and another timeseries $X_t$ given by: $X_t = at+b+R_t$
Where $a,b$ is real numbers and $R_t$ is the rest of the series (besides the linear component). Not much is known about $R_t$.
Define the differencing operator D as $D(X_t)=X_t-X_{t-1}$.
Suppose that $corr(X_t,Y_t)=0.13$
And when $D(X_t)=a+(R_t-R_{t-1})$
Also $D^2(X_t)=R_t-2*R_{t-1}+R_{t-2}$
We have $corr(D(X_t),Y_t)=0$
and $corr(D^2(X_t),Y_t)=-0.41$

Since we know that $R_t - 2*R_{t-1} + R_{t-2}$ is inversly correlated with $Y_t$
Can we conclude anything about the correlation between $R_t$ and $Y_t$ ?